# How to respond to HTTP POST from unix (AIX, RHEL, or UB) server?

Tags: unix, curl, post, slack-api, netcat

I am building a custom slash command for slack. When the slack user types a command, ex /uptime, a HTTP POST message is sent to the server URL.

The tutorials I've read all include installing a tool such as ngrok, pagekite, or localtunnel to generate a URL for the local machine.

Since I am working with a server, can I not just open a port and have slack connect directly to that hostname and port? How can I do this?

Doing some research, I came across opening a port with nc, then listening with curl, however I don't understand how to put it all together.

Comment: I think the software that answers HTTP request is called _web-server_. Apache is a well-known example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are running your script for handling the POST requests from Slack on a server that has a URL that can be reached on the Internet you do not need a local tunnel like ngrok.

If you starting from scratch I can recommend using a standard Apache + PHP [+ MySql] stack and have a PHP script to interpret and react to the POST request. Of course other script languages (e.g. Python) work just as well.